# CC2540 USB Dongle and CC2540 Keyfob communication in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have made a serial write and read code in visual studio and i want to transfer the writes through bluetooth 4.0 (low power bluetooth) in C#. I want to use a CC2540 bluetooth 4.0 usb dongle kit as transmitter, and a CC2540 bluetooth 4.0 keyfob kit as a receiver.

What should i do step by step ?. My code works in basic serial port communication.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [C# demo code](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Category%3aHealthDemo) at the TI BTLE Wiki. It implements half of what you need (the Central) in C#. Load the HostTestRelease firmware on the CC2540 that goes into the PC.

The KeyFob already has the peripheral loaded when you buy it. The TI Wiki has many examples how to communicate with the KeyFob.